# Ошибка в отступах

Tags: python, python-3.x

При исполнении выскакивает следующая ошибка,указывает на первое двоеточие в конструкции if и пишет "Invalid syntax" в чем она заключается никак не пойму. Помогите, пожалуйста. Код:

```
import json  
import os  
import hashlib  

blockchain_dir = os.curdir + '/blockchain/'


def get_hash(filename):
    file = open(blockchain_dir + filename, 'rb').read()
    return hashlib.sha256(file).hexdigest()

def get_files():
    files = os.listdir(blockchain_dir)
    return  sorted((int(i) for i in files))

def check_integrity():
    files = get_files()
    results = []

    for file in fales[1:]:
        f = open(blockchain_dir + str(file))
        h = json.load(f)['hash'] # Получить хэши

        prev_file = str(file - 1)
        actual_hash = get_hash(str(prev_file) # Еще раз получить хэши

         if  h == actual_hash:
             res = 'OK'
         else:
            res = 'Changed'

    results.append({'block': prev_file, 'result': res})

    return results

def write_block(name, polis, diagnos, prev_hash=' '): 
    files = get_files()
    prev_file = files[-1] 

    filename = str(last_file + 1) 

    prev_hash = get_hash(str(prev_file)) # Переопределил хеш

    data = {'name' :  name,
            'polis':  polis,
            'diagnos':  diagnos,
             'hash':  prev_hash}    

    with open(blockchain_dir + filename, 'w') as file: 
    json.dump(data, file, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)  
def main():
    print(chech_integrity())
if '__name__' == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Где ошибка-то? Нам угадать ее надо?

Comment: Подредактировал, указал ошибку. Извините

Comment: Ну если ошибка в отступах, то сделайте конструкцию `if` на одном уровне с телом `for` выше... То есть на одном уровне со строкой `actual_hash = get_hash(str(prev_file)`

Comment: Все отступы должны быть одинаковы. Пробелом больше, пробелом меньше - расстрел!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас сразу несколько ошибок:

1) Сместились отступы

2) Нет закрывающей скобки

Ошибка `Invalid syntaxis` вызвана тем, что парсер ожидает символ `)`, а нашел символ `:`.

```
for file in fales[1:]:
    f = open(blockchain_dir + str(file))
    h = json.load(f)['hash'] # Получить хэши

    prev_file = str(file - 1)
    actual_hash = get_hash(str(prev_file)) # <--- Тут скобка потерялась


    if h == actual_hash: # <--- Тут были проблемы с пробелом
        res = 'OK'
    else:                # <--- Тут были проблемы с пробелом
        res = 'Changed' 

results.append({'block': prev_file, 'result': res})

return results

....
 with open(blockchain_dir + filename, 'w') as file: 
    json.dump(data, file, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)  #<--- А тут отступ вообще потерялся
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, увидел ошибки. Ну и последний вопрос, это так и должно быть, что новые блоки не создаются, или снова ошибка в коде?

Answer (score 4):

Там не только ошибки с отступами были, еще и опечатки.

Пример опечаток:

- Объявлено так `files = get_files()`, а используется так: `for file in fales[1:]`:
- Объявлено так `def check_integrity():`, а вызывается так: `print(chech_integrity())`

Хотя бы запускается:

```
import json
import hashlib
import os

blockchain_dir = os.curdir + '/blockchain/'


def get_hash(filename):
    file = open(blockchain_dir + filename, 'rb').read()
    return hashlib.sha256(file).hexdigest()


def get_files():
    files = os.listdir(blockchain_dir)
    return sorted((int(i) for i in files))


def check_integrity():
    files = get_files()
    results = []

    for file in files[1:]:
        f = open(blockchain_dir + str(file))
        h = json.load(f)['hash']  # Получить хэши

        prev_file = str(file - 1)
        actual_hash = get_hash(str(prev_file))  # Еще раз получить хэши

        if h == actual_hash:
            res = 'OK'
        else:
            res = 'Changed'

    results.append({'block': prev_file, 'result': res})

    return results


def write_block(name, polis, diagnos, last_file, prev_hash=' '):
    files = get_files()
    prev_file = files[-1]

    filename = str(last_file + 1)

    prev_hash = get_hash(str(prev_file))  # Переопределил хеш

    data = {
        'name': name,
        'polis': polis,
        'diagnos': diagnos,
        'hash': prev_hash
    }

    with open(blockchain_dir + filename, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)


def main():
    print(check_integrity())


if '__name__' == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Используйте `IDE` при разработке, например, `PyCharm`, это помогает в выявлении опечаток.

Comment: Вот бы последнюю фразу из вашего ответа в заголовке сайта красными буквами.